# Sorting a dictionary and returning the result as a dictionary in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary

```
s={'a': 0, 'i': 0, 'm': 1, 'l': 0, 'q': 0, 'u': 0}
```

I would like to sort it by value and the result should be a dictonary. The output of the sorting should be:

`s={'a': 0, 'q': 0, 'u': 0, 'i': 0, 'm': 1, 'l': 1}`

How can I do This ?

Comment: The result cannot be a plain dictionary, because dictionaries are not ordered in Python. You would have sorted it for nothing.

Comment: You could sort a list of keys, for example, but cannot sort the dictionary itself. Python dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: If your version of Python is recent enough (2.7 or 3.1+), use an `OrderedDict`, which remembers insertion order. Look in the official documentation, which also gives a recipe to do exactly what you want.

Comment: What is the application for this ? There might be a better way to do it directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Sort a dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard dictionary cannot be sorted, you may want to use a list of tuples if you are not using the dictionary for indexing or use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), it will remember the order in which items were added.